# Use A&M Nav menu in entry

Tags: navigation

Is it possible to include an [A&M Nav](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/a-m-navigation) menu in an entry? 
I know Wordpress uses shortcodes for such things.  I see there is also a shortcodes plugin, but is it difficult to adapt A&M nav into that?

Comment: What is A&M Nav? (Google gets me to Texas A&M...)

Comment: http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/a-m-navigation